# Azure Function custom API Authentication

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I got a HTTP triggered azure function, which is using by one of my web applications. The user of this site would be anybody who signed up to the site. Now I want to implement authentication to the azure function in such a way that only signed up user would able access the azure function through my web site. I could see many built-in authentications like azure functions, OAuth using Azure AD and other identity providers etc. I am looking for to way to authenticate users signed-up through my website, not with identity providers.

One solution I can think of is while signing up a register that user to Azure AD. Then while calling the API pass user credentials to the API and validate against AD. Can somebody please advice this is a good solution? If not please advise the best solution for my use case.

I don't want to use any external auth provider

Answer (score 3):

Just referring to the documentation:

- [Azure functions HTTP Trigger - Authorization keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys)

  > While keys may help obfuscate your HTTP endpoints during development, they are not intended as a way to secure an HTTP trigger in production. To learn more, see [Secure an HTTP endpoint in production](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#secure-an-http-endpoint-in-production).
- The second link [Secure an HTTP endpoint in production](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#secure-an-http-endpoint-in-production) gives more insights on how to secure HTTP triggered functions:

  > To fully secure your function endpoints in production, you should consider implementing one of the following function app-level security options:
  >
  > - Turn on App Service Authentication / Authorization for your function app. The App Service platform lets use Azure Active Directory (AAD) and several third-party identity providers to authenticate clients. You can use this to implement custom authorization rules for your functions, and you can work with user information from your function code. To learn more, see [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service and Working with client identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization).
  > - Use Azure API Management (APIM) to authenticate requests. APIM provides a variety of API security options for incoming requests. To learn more, see [API Management authentication policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies). With APIM in place, you can configure your function app to accept requests only from the IP address of your APIM instance. To learn more, see [IP address restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#ip-address-restrictions).
  > - Deploy your function app to an Azure App Service Environment (ASE). ASE provides a dedicated hosting environment in which to run your functions. ASE lets you configure a single front-end gateway that you can use to authenticate all incoming requests. For more information, see [Configuring a Web Application Firewall (WAF) for App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-app-service-environment-web-application-firewall).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you can do this in following ways.

**Using function level Authorization key (Not preferred but easy)**

If your web app is the only one that will access the function app you may enable authorization directly on the function. Any one who wants to access the function has to pass the key else you get 401 . Since you want your function to be accessed directly by users then you have to create additonal end point in your web site that will call function app on users' behalf and pass the key. You can find more about here 
[Authorization Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys)

**Using Azure B2C or AD**

You are thinking on the right lines. If your website is external consumer accessed then you may consider Azure B2C. You get many out of box functionalities including sign up using social logins and you may not need to save the users separately.  The flow remains the same , users get authenticated by Azure AD (or B2C) and token is issued. The token is then passed when calling azure functions.